# Contender's gears vs. Crafted Dreadful gears

Tags: world-of-warcraft

My toon is going to hit level 90 very soon and I am looking for gearing guides. Multiple sources point me to [this guide](http://www.wowhead.com/guide=577/gearing-up-when-you-hit-90), where it is stated that if I go the crafting route, I should get the [Contender's gears](http://www.wowhead.com/search?q=contender), which are iLvl 450 pieces. There are several other guides also mentioned the Contender's gears.

Then I searched on the AH. Instead of the Contender's, I saw a lot of [Crafted Dreadful gears](http://www.wowhead.com/search?q=crafted%20dreadful) that are iLvl 458 items and has better stats. It seems these are better than Contender's in all aspects as long as I can afford them.

I am looking to confirm if the gearing guides did not mention Crafted Dreadful gears because the guides are outdated, or there are hidden gotchas and I should still get the Contender's pieces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why that guide fails to mention the Crafted Dreadful Gladiator's ilvl 458 PvP pieces. They've been around since Patch 5.2, and that guide appears to have been updated since then. It must be simply an oversight.

These items are fine to use for PvP until you grind out enough honor or conquest points to purchase higher level items. Though as you'll be undergeared compared to most other players, I suggest sticking to regular battlegrounds until you get better geared.

If you're *not* doing PvP, I wouldn't bother with these at all. You can get better PvE items from vendors for gold or trivial amounts of justice or valor points, though you'll have to shop carefully.

Comment: Now that you have 60% base resilience, PvE items are actually viable at higher levels now as well.

Comment: @deutschZuid True, but I don't want my Frostbolts to hit like wet noodles, either. It's a balancing act. That's why I suggest avoiding RBG/Arena until you at least have full or mostly full Honor gear.